ValueError: time data does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
While running the following code I'm getting following error
ValueError: time data '2024-04-27T04:50:23.3480072Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
Here is my python code
from datetime import datetime

time_string = '2024-04-27T04:50:23.3480072Z'
format_string = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'

parsed_time = datetime.strptime(time_string, format_string)
print(parsed_time)

I'm passing the correct date format string still getting error.

The %f format matches exactly six decimal digits.  You have 7.  Have you tried .fromisoformat?

Yes getting this error ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2024-04-27T04:50:23.3480072'

If you can't figure out any other solution, you might just need to cut off the last 2 characters of the time_string and modify your format_string to not include the Z. Then you can do something like datetime.strptime(time_string[0:-2], format_string). Not exactly my favorite solution, but it works.

datetime.fromisoformat('2024-04-27T04:50:23.3480072Z') will not raise a ValueError

@SIGHUP is correct, but with a caveat. You can use datetime.fromisoformat for that string but only on Python versions 3.11 and later. You probably need to update your Python version.

If you know (for certain) that the number of decimal seconds is always exactly 7 you can truncate the input value by 2 characters and also remove the unnecessary Z from the format string as follows:
from datetime import datetime

time_string = '2024-04-27T04:50:23.3480072Z'
format_string = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f' # <--- Z removed

parsed_time = datetime.strptime(time_string[:-2], format_string)
print(parsed_time)

Output:
2024-04-27 04:50:23.348007

Note:
The %f format character handles up to 6 decimal places - i.e., there could be fewer than 6 and it would still work
However:
What if the number of decimal places in the date/time string is unknown? The code shown above is only reliable if there are exactly 7 decimal places. In order to handle situations where there could be any number of decimal places you need extract that part of the string, examine it in terms of its length then modify the string (if necessary) by some variable amount. You could achieve this with:
from datetime import datetime
import re

time_string = "2024-04-27T04:50:23.34812345Z"
format_string = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"

m = re.search(r".*\.(\d+)Z$", time_string)

if m:
    dp = len(m.group(1))
    if dp > 6:
        time_string = time_string[: 5 - dp]  # truncate decimal places and remove Z
    else:
        time_string = time_string[:-1]  # remove Z

parsed_time = datetime.strptime(time_string, format_string)
print(parsed_time)


You probably want to use datetime.fromisoformat as that would be the simplest way to parse this perfectly compliant ISO-8601 date string. However, Python versions earlier than 3.11 can only parse a value with 3 or 6 decimal places as discussed in this GitHub issue. Since you said you got a ValueError when using datetime.fromisoformat in the comments, you will need to update your Python version first.

Python < 3.11 fromisoformat also cannot parse 'Z' to UTC

The %f format matches exactly six decimal digits.
time_string = '2024-04-27T04:50:23.348007Z'

from datetime import datetime

time_string = '2024-04-27T04:50:23.348007Z'
format_string = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'

parsed_time = datetime.strptime(time_string, format_string)
print(parsed_time)


I think it's a pretty reasonable assumption that he does not have control over the time string in the code he's actually working with.

Well, don't we ALWAYS have control over our strings?  ;)
